# How to programmatically set the image in the ngx-img-cropper component?

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm attempting to use the `ngx-img-cropper` control: https://github.com/web-dave/ngx-img-cropper.

If I use the Cropper's own file input control, populating the canvas works fine. However, I can't figure out how to get an image selected by other means into the component.

Declaring View Children for an `<img>` element and the `<img-cropper>` component:

```js
@ViewChild("image")
private _image: HTMLImageElement;

@ViewChild("cropper", undefined)
private _cropper: ImageCropperComponent;
```

In the `(load)` event handler for the `<img>` element, I attempt to set the Cropper's image like this.

```
if (this._cropper) {
    this._cropper.setImage(this._image);
}
```

However, the cropper's canvas never updates with the image; although the `(imageSet)` event handler is called.

Besides using an `<img>` tag, I've attempted to programmaticaly retrieve the image from the server and load it, but that failed as the Cropper component does not exist when the FileReader's Load or LoadEnd events occur.

```
private _imageBase64: string;

// Also tried ngAfterViewInit, but failed the same way.
public ngOnInit() {
    // ...
    this._imageService.GetImage()
        .subscribe({
            "next": data => { this.createImageFromBlob(data); }
        });
}

private createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    // also tried the onload event
    reader.onloadend = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
        this._imageBase64 = reader.result;
        this._cropper.inputImage = this._imageBase64;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}
```

Any suggestions for how I can get a server provided image programmatically loaded into the `ngx-img-cropper` component for editing?

### EDIT

`this._cropper` did not exist because the component's element was inside an `*ngIf` controlled element where the condition evaluated to `false`. StackOverflow has other questions and answers dealing with that issue.

So, after fixing the above problem, the Cropper is now populated with my image, and I can drag the selection corners and the whole selection. But, the `ngx-img-cropper` component itself is now generating errors:

```
TypeError: Unable to set property 'image' of undefined or null reference
```

It appears a property used by the component is lacking a value... (this may be a bug or me simply failing to properly initialize the component).

Answer (score 2):

Although I was unable to programmatically pull the `<img>` tag reference and apply it to the image cropper, after fixing the `*ngIf` issue with the cropper not being present in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, I was able to programmatically set the image by dynamically creating an `Image` instance, setting its `src` property to the `FileReader`'s output and then calling `setImage()` with that dynamic Image instance.

```js
photoEdit._imageBase64 = reader.result;
this._image = new Image();
this._image.src = photoEdit._imageBase64;
photoEdit._cropper.setImage(this._image);
```

As for the other error, that was fixed by manually populating the `image` property within my `imageSet` event handler for the image cropper component. I suspect this is a bug in the component as it should do this automatically when the `setImage` method is called.

```js
public onImageSet(image: any) {
    this._cropper.image = image;
}
```